# как получить доступ к GPS в виндовсе с помощью питона

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Недавно увидел статью как получить GPS координаты на андроид и мне стало интересно можно ли сделать такое же только для ноута который работает на винде вот это статья https://qna.habr.com/q/637307

Comment: GPS-то в ноуте есть?

Comment: А вообще https://stackoverflow.com/a/73784647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import winsdk.windows.devices.geolocation as wdg


def getCoords():
    locator = wdg.Geolocator()
    pos = await locator.get_geoposition_async()
    return [pos.coordinate.latitude, pos.coordinate.longitude]
```